# Can't find subview elements in IOS-UIAutomation

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I have the following hierarchy of views
MainView -> SubViewA -> ChildA,ChildB,ChildC

The logElementTree() is unable to print the subview elements for the View "SubViewA". (All the views have accessibilityLabel)

Comment: The SubViewA is serving as a container for other items that should be accessible. Thus Such a view should implement the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol and set this property to NO.

UIAccessibility protocol- check isAccessibilityElement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UI Automation element finds no sub-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821713/ios-ui-automation-element-finds-no-sub-elements)